# I want to know how much user/ IP is online and which user is using high bandwidth on my network.?

Tags: networking, ip, lan, bandwidth

I want to know how much User/IP are currently online or running and How much  User/IP is offline/Shutdown. 
And which user is using high bandwidth (LAN/WAN) on my network... Please HELP ?

I want a graphically solution like WHATSUP GOLD but WHATSUP GOLD is so costly and i want a free software.

I have 30-40 Node i my network.

Comment: put spy cameras on all your users! See who is streaming video's.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/896/windows-program-to-monitor-how-much-bandwidth-network-users-are-using

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the structure of your network, [EtherApe](http://etherape.sourceforge.net/) is a graphical network monitor, but it's more for active monitoring, not logging to a file.

You could use [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) to capture data over a long period and then use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to analyse that data and get visual representations.

This all really depends on your network structure though, is all of your network traffic being routed through a server you can run these programs from? If not you will only get partial data.

Comment: +1: *This all really depends on your network structure though, is all of your network traffic being routed through a server you can run these programs from? If not you will only get partial data.* Without an appliance at the end, partial data is the best case scenario.